# Slow down AutoIt without explicit Sleep() statements

Tags: autoit

I am trying to explore AutoIt for automation. Is there a way to increase execution time (wait) rather than use Sleep(3000) after each syntax/command?

Answer (score 4):

The interval between key presses and mouse clicks can be set with [AutoItSetOption](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm), with parameters "MouseClickDownDelay" and "SendKeyDelay", respectively. This will cause a general slowdown of the script without requiring `Sleep` statements.

Sample:

```
AutoItSetOption("MouseClickDownDelay", 200)  ; Unit: ms. "Alters the length a click is held
                                             ; down before release."

AutoItSetOption("SendKeyDelay", 100)  ; Unit: ms.  "Alters the length of the brief pause in
                                      ;            between sent keystrokes. A value of 0 removes
                                      ;            the delay completely."
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Sleep()` function pauses script execution. When you say "increase execution time", it sounds like you are waiting on something instead of just trying to pause the script.

Check out the following functions in the AutoIt help:

- `ProcessWait()`
- `RunWait()`
- `ShellExecuteWait()`
- `WinWait()`
- `WinWaitActivate()`
- `WinWaitClose()`
- `WinWaitDelay` *(this is an option, not a function)*
- `WinWaitNotActive()`

Maybe one of these will help you with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think what he wants is a way to pause or slow down the execution of the script between each line, probably for debugging.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem using a command line configuration tool, and cannot find any suitable solution. The problem is following:
My command line configuration tool (which is 'psadmin' for peoplesoft config) is a command line menu which proposes options. Each option generate an action which last an unpredictable time, depending on computer performances, other threads, etc. A Sleep(###) is not appropriate since the action duration is unknown and fluctuant.
Therefore, it would be cool if AutoIt could detect when prompt is available again (eventually based on regex expression)