# Is it possbile to set sleep() time in autoit to a not specific time/parameter?

Tags: sleep, autoit

Is it possible to adjust the sleep() time (in autoit) to the time that the function being executed finishes, because setting a specific time value can ending up not being enough to the function.
( This function runs VietOCR and basically converts a PDF file to a TXT and sends it to another directory).

If the file is too big, the function will take more time and if I set for example 40 secs in "Sleep()" and the file isn't converted/moved yet, there's an error because the directory I will use ahead ( in the script, with the converted file) is empty.

Thanks for reading and sorry if i messed anything up, I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow down AutoIt without explicit Sleep() statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526223/slow-down-autoit-without-explicit-sleep-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are waiting for an exe to finish that you start in your code, you should use the function "[RunWait()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm)".

That might not work for your case. You can also just sleep until a file exists.

```
func waitForFileToExist($fileName)
  while 1
    if (FileExists($fileName)) Then
     ExitLoop
    EndIf
    sleep(1000)
  WEnd   
EndFunc
```